# Tomcat Manager: Is it possible to avoid url parameters?

Tags: url, tomcat

My problem is that when I'm reloading my application at tomcat manager it sometimes fails due to the old parameters in the url. This is because the tomcat manager adds some parameters to the url by pressing reload on an application. 
This changes the url from

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/reload?path=/backoffice&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=6FD31EC1
```

When I reload the page tomcat manager wants to send the form data again, which is not what i want to do. So I wondered if it's possible to switch to http post or if there is any other way to avoid this?